# selenium chromedriver different values of xpath between terminal and actual driver

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
url = 'https://www.msha.gov/mine-data-retrieval-system'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver')
driver.get(url)
#driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mstr90"]/div[1]/div/div') error
#driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input') gives 3 while in driver gives 10
```

I am unable to find element where the input "Search by Mine ID by typing here.." is, the document is fully loaded but it can't locate it. What I want to do is simply pass in an input "0100003" then submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iframe is present on your page. Before you interact with inputbox you need to switch on to iframee. Refer below code to resolve your issue.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://www.msha.gov/mine-data-retrieval-system")

driver.switch_to.frame("iframe1")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
inputBox = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='mstrmojo-SimpleObjectInputBox-empty']"))).click()
inputBox1 = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='mstrmojo-SimpleObjectInputBox-container mstrmojo-scrollNode']//input")))
inputBox1.send_keys("0100003")
```

**Updated Code to handle dropdown**

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#mstr100,mstrmojo-Popup.mstrmojo.SearchBoxSelector-suggest"))).click()
```

Note: please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: can you just add the click on item which gets from drop menu

Comment: which drop down please provide detail information as so many drop down arre present on the page . Also your original question dont have any information related to drop down so I think your sending text is resolved as per main question

Comment: in the picture, after you send "0100003" a drop menu is shown with the value of "0100003" , it needs  to be clicked

Comment: @User1984: Can you please accept answer from your end ?

Answer (score 0):

The element you are trying to find is inside an iframe, so you will need to switch to that iframe first and then do your find element.  Also, it's a best practice to use waits to give pages/elements time to load before a find element timeouts and throws an error.

```
iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#iframe1')))

driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

mine_id = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mstr90"]/div[1]/div/div')))
```

Then you need to click this element to make it interactable.

```
mine_id.click()
```

Once you click then you need to re-find the input box before sending keys.

```
mine_id_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#mstr90 input')))

mine_id_input.send_keys('0100003')
```

To select the suggestion displayed:

```
suggestion = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#mstr100')))

suggestion.click()
```

if you wanted to continue on interacting outside the iframe after this is done, you will want to switch back out of the iframe like this:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: it's just missing the click on "drop menu" so I can actually submit

Comment: I've added to my answer to help get through the popup that's displayed